# Finding the recently deleted entities using Hibernate envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

So my problem is that I need to find all the recently deleted entities of a particular class, that is the entities which have been deleted since a particular timestamp. Specifically, I want to find entities deleted within the last hour.

All my entities have a created and updated timestamp which I maintain correctly with a listener:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "updated")
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime updated;
```

I also use Envers and annotate my entities.

So to guess, my query should start like this:

```
// Query for deleted bookings
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()
.forRevisionsOfEntity(Booking.class, false, true)
```

but I don't know what to put here to find the deleted Booking's since a DateTime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, get a timestamp for one hour ago (in milliseconds):

```
long timestamp = (System.getCurrentTimeMillis()) - (60*60*1000);
```

Then you can query relative to the timestamp:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()
.forRevisionsOfEntity(Booking.class, false, true)
.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").gt(timestamp)
.add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.DEL));

List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

to get the revision data. Each `Object[]` has

1. revision meta data (`DefaultRevisionEntity` or your own class annotated with `@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)`)
2. the entity instance (the `Booking` in this case)
3. the `RevisionType`, which we know will always be `DEL` in this case

Answer (score 3):

I find the Envers API quite limited and sometimes have to turn to use just plain JPA. However, this is not one of those cases, I believe you can achieve your use case by doing the following:

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(classType, false, true)
        .add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.DEL))
        .addProjection(AuditEntity.property(ID).distinct())
        .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().gt(revisionNumber);
```

The above example uses the revision number but you could easily retrieve the revision number from the start date you are looking for.